# Как исключить Get из htaccess при обрезании .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Необходимо обрезать .php в урле, но при имеющемся коде (ниже) в htacess перестают корректно работать некоторые скрипты с Get параметрами. Как туда (в код ниже) правильно дописать `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET` чтобы работала и обрезка .php и post и get?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(\S+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: чтобы get-параметры сохранялись надо флаг `QSA` дописать и все, а не вот этот вот

Comment: если можно, пример, не очень понимаю о чём вы

Answer (score 0):

Явно передать GET-параметры можно из переменной %{QUERY_STRING}. И у вас там 2 правила, к какому правилу вы хотите добавить условие?
Если к первому, то так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(\S+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ %1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: если так, то скрипты работают, но .php в урле не отрезается.

Comment: других вариантов нет?)

Comment: Конечно не отрезаются вы же туда добавили условие
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
это значит что он игнорирует все гет-запросы

Comment: так получается нельзя, чтобы и гет были и .php отрезалось?

Comment: Можно, уберите условие
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
тогда обрезание .php будет работать в гет-запросах, иначе обрезание работает во всех запроса кроме POST и GET. Я не знаю зачем вы хотели это условие туда добавить?